# Is it possible to break demands in several vehicles in a vrp python ortools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to solve a VRP with time windows and demands constraints using python ortools. But my model consider a whole demand for a single vehicle.

My question is:

- Can i break a demand in several vehicles considering the cost function? That is, the model chooses the number of vehicles and their proportions.

Comment: Please provide what you already tried. Help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, solver can only visit each node one time (TSP solver BTW).

You have to split your node in several nodes manualy...

ps: see https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1246#issuecomment-489105446